# reading till EOF from standard input in c

Tags: c, fread

i am using a Unix machine and i am trying to read from console till EOF is reached (am supplying with Ctrl+D) . I am using fread_unlocked, For the input read, it outputs the read integers correclty but instead of a normal exit , it gives segmentation fault on EOF . How do i modify my code so that it behaves as expected?

```
int MAXX = 10000000;
char *ipos, InpFile[MAXX];

inline int input_int(int flag=0)
{
  while(*ipos<=32)
    ++ipos;
 if(flag)
    return(*ipos++-'0');
 LL x=0,neg=0;
 char c;
 while(true)
  {
    c=*ipos++;
    if(c=='-')
        neg=1;
    else
    {
        if(c<=32)
         return neg?-x:x;x=(x<<1)+(x<<3)+c-'0';
    }
  }
 }
int main()
{
   ipos = InpFile;
   fread_unlocked(InpFile, MAXX, 1, stdin);
   while(true){
   int n = input_int();
   printf("%d\n",n);
   }
   return 0;
}
```

My input from the console is : `3 4 5 6Ctrl+D` 
THe output i get now is :       `3 4 5 6 Segmentation Error`
Expected output:                `3 4 5 6`
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`fread_unlocked` returns the number of bytes that were actually read. You need to take that return value, and you need to make sure that you never try to use more than that many characters out of `InpFile`. For example, if you declare `max_ipos` at global scope, you might write:

```
size_t bytes_read = fread_unlocked(InpFile, 1, MAXX, stdin);
// check for errors
max_ipos = &InpFile[bytes_read];
```

and then `input_int` will need to detect when `ipos == max_ipos` and terminate before reading `*ipos`.

**Edited to add:** Note that (at the suggestion of Jonathan Leffler) I've switched the order of the arguments `1` and `MAXX` to `fread_unlocked`. This is because you want to read objects of size `1`, not objects of size `MAXX`.

Incidentally, this:

```
inline int input_int(int flag=0)
```

is not valid C. Default values for arguments are a C++ thing. (Maybe there are C compilers that support it as an extension — I don't know — but there are definitely C compilers that don't.)

Comment: Actually, the order of the arguments to `fread()` (and hence `fread_unlocked()` are `size_t fread(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nitems, FILE *stream);`, so the `fread()` call will return 0 unless the user types `MAXX` characters (which we can be confident won't happen since `MAXX` is 10 million), the return value from `fread()` will be zero.  Reorder the arguments (`1, MAXX`) and then you get useful information.  And yes, I still look at the man page for `fread()` before I use it, every time.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: That's an excellent point. I've updated my answer, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your code is very dirty code and everyone one to read it, be sure , will be confuse, So , i clean your code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int MAXX = 10000000;
char x = 0 ; 
char *ipos = &x, InpFile[10000000];

inline int input_int(int flag=0){
  while( *::ipos <= 32 )
    ++::ipos;
  if(flag)
     return(*::ipos++) -'0';
  char x = 0 , neg = 0;
  char c = ' ';
  while ( true ) {
      c = (*::ipos++);
      if(c == '-')
          neg = 1;
      else {
          if(c <= 32)
              return neg ? -x : x; 
          x = (x << 1) + (x << 3) + c -'0';
      }
  }
}

int main(){
   ipos = InpFile;
   fread_unlocked(InpFile, MAXX, 1, stdin);
   while ( true ) {
       int n = input_int();
       printf( " %d \n " , n);
   }
   return 0;
}
```

By the way, You didn't mention to job of your program.
Another your problem: you didn't initialize your ipos pointer.If you want to working with pointers, don't forget to initialize them.